# Populate a HTML SELECT using SQL and CF with a condition

Tags: html, sql, coldfusion, forms, cfquery

I would like to populate 2 HTML elements SELECT using CF and SQL, the 1st select gets is options from all the elements in the TABLE Stakes, the 2nd SELECT gets is options from the TABLE Wards where the elements have the same StakeId as in the option selected in the 1st SELECT.
I been trying to do this for hours, but i can't get to work the 2nd SELECT.
Here is my code:

1st SELECT

```
<CFQUERY NAME="getStakes" DATASOURCE="#APPLICATION.ds#">
    SELECT * FROM Estacas
</CFQUERY>

<SELECT NAME="Stakes">
    <CFOUTPUT QUERY="getStakes">
        <OPTION VALUE="#estId#">#estName#</OPTION>
    </CFOUTPUT>
</SELECT>
```

2nd SELECT

```
<CFQUERY NAME="getWards" DATASOURCE="#APPLICATION.ds#">
    SELECT * FROM Alas WHERE estId = form.Stakes
</CFQUERY>

<SELECT NAME="Stakes">
    <CFOUTPUT QUERY="getWards">
        <OPTION VALUE="alaId">#alaName#</OPTION>
    </CFOUTPUT>
</SELECT>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You will need to use more than just CF and HTML. In order to load options in the 2nd `<select>` after the 1st `<select>` is chosen, you will need to use JavaScript. There are even ColdFusion libraries to help facilitate this in ColdFusion. Do a search for 'ColdFusion related selects' - but disregard any solutions that use `cfajaxproxy`

Comment: The simplest way to do this is with the bind attribute of the cfselect tag.  The documentation for this tag has an example.

Comment: Don't use `cfselect`...it will paint you into a corner. learn how to do it the correct way now and save yourself trouble down the road.

Comment: And if i instead use one select tag where the <optgroup> is the stake and the options are the wards?

Comment: I agree with Scott - but to be fair Dan did say "the simplest way" and he's probably right :)

Comment: I am not sure I agree using `cfselect` is the 'easiest' :D If you want to use one select box with `<optgroup>` it would be best to use a single query that joins the 2 tables and then use the `group` attribute on `cfoutput`

Comment: Whether you use two selects or one with an optgroup depends on what you are trying to accomplish.  You are the only one who knows that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally find out the best way to solve my problem using only cf and html, Scott Stroz was right, about using the group attribute but back then i had no clue what he was talking about, this way there is no need to use other languages, like javascript.
Thanks Scott even though i just found out what you were talking about after knowing this lol.

```
<cfquery name="getAlasEstacas" datasource="#APPLICATION.ds#">
    SELECT a.alaId, a.alaName, e.estName 
    FROM alas a
    INNER JOIN estacas e ON e.estId = a.estId
    ORDER BY e.estName, a.alaName
</cfquery>
<select name="AlaId">
    <cfoutput query="getAlasEstacas" group="estName">
        <optgroup label="#estName#">
            <cfoutput>
                <option value="#alaId#">#alaName#</option>
            </cfoutput>
        </optgroup>
    </cfoutput>
</select>
```